A term equation
Let $t,a$ are some terms in a first-order language, $x$ is a free variable,
the notation $t[x:=a]$ denotes the rezult of replacement in $t$ every occurrence of $x$ with $a$.
Suppose, we have a term equation $Z[x:=a] = t$, where $Z$ is a term variable.
If $a$ is a free variable, $t$ does not contain $x$, then a solution is $Z = t[a:=x]$ because $Z[x:=a] = t[a:=x][x:=a] = t$.
In which other cases can we solve this equation?

Have you tried looking for any simple examples that aren't of this form?

@D.W The term $a$ can also be a constant symbol.

Suppose that $z[x := a] = t$ for some term $z$.
The following cases are possible:

$t$ does not contain $a$. Then $z$ does not contain $x$ and therefore $z[x := a] = z$.
So $z = t$. Note, that $t$ does not contain $x$.
It means that if $t$ does contain $x$ then the term equation  $Z[x := a] = t$ has no solutions,
otherwise the solution is $Z = t$.

$t$ does contain $a$ and the following condition $N$ holds:
For every occurrence $\alpha$ of $x$ in $t$, the term $a$ is $x$ or an ancestor of  $\alpha$ in $t$.
(This condition trivially holds if $t$ does not contain $x$).
In this case, the solution is $Z =  t[a := x]$ (the result of replacing every occurrence of the subterm $a$ in $t$ with $x$).

$t$ does contain $a$ and the condition $N$ does not hold.
In this case, the term equation has no solutions.


